# Octopress deploy to project[gh-pages] css js

Tags: octopress, github-pages

I want to setup octopress blog on gh-pages branch of one of my github projects. I follow guidelines from the octopress deployment docs. My project repository url is standard: `https://github.com/my_user_name/project_name`

I follow two scenarios by neither works in some way.

### Scenario 1:

I invoke  `rake setup_github_pages` and supply it with repository location: 
`git@github.com:my_user_name/project_name.git` 
This works well and gh-pages branch is created in my project repo.

I do not change Jekill setup in `_config.yml`, in particular `root:` is empty.
`rake generate && preview` work well. I load the site on `local host:4000`. 
Css and js are loaded correctly.

Now I deploy the site: `rake generate && deploy`
I load octopress blog as: `http://my_user_name.github.io/project_name/`

**Problem**: the blog loads without `screen.css`. Moreover, I see following errors for javascript:

> [Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) (jquery.fancybox.pack.js, line 0)
>   `http://my_user_name.github.io/javascripts/jquery.fancybox.pack.js`

### Scenario 2:

Same as above, but I change `_config.yml`, in particular is set **`root: /project_name`** to the name of my project repo.

`rake generate && preview`
I load the site on `local host:4000` and now I get errors, but on my local machine:

For `screen.css`, `jquery.fancybox.pack.js` and

> [Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) (slash.js, line 0) 
>   `local host:4000/project_name/javascripts/slash.js`

Now I deploy the site: `rake generate && deploy`
Css loads correctly, while error console shows that I searches for javascript not in my project path, but at my main repo path:

> [Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) (jquery.fancybox.pack.js, line 0)
>   `http://my_user_name.github.io/javascripts/jquery.fancybox.pack.js`

---

Please advice, what am I doing wrong?

Do I use `rake setup_github_pages` incorrectly?
Do I setup `root` in `_config.yml` incorrectly?
Or is there some additional setup information that has to be resolved?

Answer (score 0):

Answering myself. There are two issues here.

First, `rake set_root_dir[dir_name]`. This has never been mentioned on StackOverflow: 
There is a separate step specified for deploying projects to Github's project pages (not user pages) in addition to what is specified in `http://octopress.org/docs/deploying/github/`. Unfortunately it's not directly seen in that documentation.
The step http://octopress.org/docs/deploying/subdir/ requires running `rake set_root_dir[project_name]` and a few modifications to `Rakefile` and `config.rb`.
This resolves the paths correctly for octopress published in Github's project pages ([gh-pages] branch) or in subdirectories.

The second issue seems to be related to how the paths to resources (`jquery.fancybox.pack.js` in my case) have to be resolved for **custom themes**, when octopress is deployed to Github's project pages (subdirectory). 
One has to check that a custom theme has paths adjusted to {{ root_url }} for fonts, css and js as well.